# How to cd open / autocomplete a folder that ends in a specific phrase

Tags: linux, bash, autocomplete, wildcard, cd

I have a folder with subfolders named like this:

```
1122334 important things
1122335 less important things
1122336 notes
1122337 pictures of kittens
```

etc

The numbers at the beginning are date codes. If it was up to me, I would put the date codes at the end, but it isn't.

In bash, I'd like to do something like this:

```
$ cd *pictu<tab>
```

and get this

```
$ cd 1122337\ pictures\ of\ kittens/
```

Is there a simple way to do this, or something I can put in my `.bashrc` to make this possible?

Comment: unix.stackexchange.com would probably be a better place to ask this non-programming question.

Comment: Thanks, I will post this there as well and transfer the answer here if I get one.

Answer (score 1):

from terdon: [How to cd open / autocomplete a folder that ends in a specific phrase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959058/how-to-cd-open-autocomplete-a-folder-that-ends-in-a-specific-phrase)

As far as I know, there is no way of making bash autocomplete `*pictu` here are some workarounds:

1. Don't use <kbd>TAB</kbd>, just `cd` directly using wildcards before and after the pattern:

   ```
   $ cd *pictu*
   ```

   That will move you into the first directory whose name contains `pic`.
2. Use two wildcards and *then* <kbd>TAB</kbd>:

   ```
   $ cd *pictu*<TAB>
   ```

   That should expand to `cd 1122337\ pictures\ of\ kittens/`
3. Use another shell. `zsh` has a cool feature, you can do:

   ```
   ➜ cd pictu<tab>
   ```

   and that expands to `➜ cd 1122337\ pictures\ of\ kittens/`.